# LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY not working in API 21

Tags: android, location, google-play-services

I'm trying to enable the location system settings and setting it to HIGH ACCURACY.
The code works well on API above 21 as I press OK, the location setting is turned On and set to HIGH ACCURACY but for the API 21 and below that the location is turned ON but set to BATTERY SAVER.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    private static final int REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS = 0x1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Log.i("LogCheck", "createLocationRequest");
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(2000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(2000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                .addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
        SettingsClient client = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(this);
        Task<LocationSettingsResponse> task = client.checkLocationSettings(builder.build());
        task.addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LocationSettingsResponse locationSettingsResponse) {
                mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
            }
        });

        task.addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                if (e instanceof ResolvableApiException) {
                    // Location settings are not satisfied, but this can be fixed
                    // by showing the user a dialog.
                    try {
                        // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                        // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                        ResolvableApiException resolvable = (ResolvableApiException) e;
                        resolvable.startResolutionForResult(MainActivity.this,
                                REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException sendEx) {
                        // Ignore the error.
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

[image: API 25 request]
  **API 25 request**
[image: API 25 setting]
  **API 25 setting**
[image: API 21 request]
  **API 21 request**
[image: API 21 setting]
  **API 21 setting**

As you can see in code I have requested

```
 mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
```

but It does not seem to work in API 21.

Comment: have you checked with 21  device??

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you managed to solve this problem?

Comment: No, problem still exists with the emulator but the code runs well in the physical devices. So, I guess no need to worry :)